# Update DS.RecordArray when changing routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

ive searched for this and have not found an answer. I have 2 routes: "Index", which creates/updates an expense list, and "Charts", which charts the values of the expenses.

In order to handle the expense charts, I have the following function:

```
getData: function() {
    var expenses = this.store.all('expense');
    expenses.update();
    var retarr = Ember.A();
    expenses.forEach(function(expense) {
        retarr.pushObject({
            label: expense.get('name'),
            value: expense.get('amount'),
            group: 'expense'
        });
    });
    return retarr;
}.property()
```

This is then passed to the ember-charts component in the Charts route.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id='charts'>
<div class="chart-container">
  {{horizontal-bar-chart data=getData}}
</div>
```

However, if I create/delete an expense in the "Index" route and hten transition to the "Charts" route, the DS.RecordArray doesn't update despite calling the "update()" function. As such, the chart does not reflect the created/deleted changes until the page is refreshed.

How do I fix this so the RecordArray auto updates along with the chart? I've broken my head for over two days trying different things. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a model for this?

Comment: An "Expense" is a DS.Model - I just need to convert certain fields from the model into the specific "label","value" and "group" values required by the charting API

Comment: Hum, are you sure `getData` is called on each transition? Have you tried to use `this.store.unloadAll("expense")` just before `var expenses = this.store.all('expense');`?

Comment: Just tried that - now no data is populated in the chart (i.e. it is blank).. this is very strange.

Comment: Okay so some R&D led to the finding that the "getData" function is only being called hte first time I load the "Charts" route - how do I ensure it is called every time?

Answer (score 0):

Your property `getData` should be bound to anything, if this something is an array you should use `@each`. For example as you can see [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/):

```
remaining: function() {
    var todos = this.get('todos');
    return todos.filterBy('isDone', false).get('length');
}.property('todos.@each.isDone')
```

I suggest you another approch, let's modify your model:

```
App.Chart = DS.Model.extend({
    // fieds here...

    label: function() {
        return this.get("name");
    }.property("name"),
    value: function() {
        return this.get("amount");
    }.property("amount"),
    group: function() {
        return "expense";
    }.property(),
)};
```

In your route set `myCharts` property:

```
App.ChartRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        var charts = this.store.find("chart");
        controller.set("myCharts", charts);
    }
});
```

Then you could use your horizontal chart:

```
<div class="chart-container">
  {{horizontal-bar-chart data=myCharts}}
</div>
```

Note: I didn't tested this code but it should work

Comment: hey thanks for this.. I'm guessing you mean the Expense model? I tried it this way but it gives an error in the console saying undefined is not a function etc. And if I followed the first approach, what would I apply "@each" to?